# Zombie Movie where girl realizes that zombie apocalypse happened

Tags: identify-this-movie

I saw this movie a few years ago and don't remember much about it, but I'll try my best. Pretty sure it was an indie film on Netflix.

This college-aged girl wakes up after being knocked out (tried to overdose on drugs I think) for a few days, only to realize the zombie apocalypse has struck.  She gets a call from her friend, telling her to head over to her place where they're safe.
Basically she spends the duration of the movie trying to survive, avoiding the zombies, and at one point she is held up in a cellar with another family.  The family acts terrified of her, but she is not sure why.

At the end, when she walks in to her friend's apartment, you see her from her friend's point of view, only to realize she's been a zombie the whole time!  She gets killed by her friend's boyfriend (I think), and that's the end of the film.

If anyone can tell me the name of this film, I would be eternally grateful.  it's driving me insane!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Is it [Fear Itself](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1112285/?ref_=tt_ov_inf): Season 1, Episode 6 ([New Year's Day](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1117024/)), from IMDb's synopsis all plot-line is matching.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Year%27s_Day_%28Fear_Itself%29) is full Wikipedia summary of the episode. Even the ending of the episode is matching with your provided details.

Comment: Oh wow, I was way off on thinking it was a movie.  Thank you though!!  Finally I can get some sleep :D