A recent movie about zombies who know they're dead
I remember that there were zombies who were aware of being dead. They were psychologically suffering from observing decaying of their bodies. They tried to eat real food and live normal life.
In the movie there was a girl returning home to her boyfriend just to find he became a zombie too. I remember that in the end of the movie this girl jumped out of a balcony and broke her leg, but didn't die and was sad about it because she realized she was a zombie too (or maybe she knew before the jump)
Release year: I think between 2010 - 2013
Country and language: Don't remember the country, but I think that movie was in English
I Don't remember the actor's names at all. 
I think the main character - (the girl I mentioned) was blonde with medium haircut. 
The movie title is not: Warm Bodies or Maggie
I believe that movie had low budget and wasn't advertised much in mass-media

I'm sure that that was not a TV show, that definetely was a movie

Could this be it?
https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/15598/zombie-movie-where-girl-realizes-that-zombie-apocalypse-happened

@followthemeow no, already cheked this question

Well, I have finally found this movie. It is Shatter Dead (here is a link). I told almost everything wrong - the movie was released in 1994, the girl is not blonde. At least I remember plot right. 

In a horrible turn of events, the people of this world go on living even in death. With gangs about killing people to share in their misery, and people (corpses) confused, it is indeed a bleek future. When Susan, not yet dead, is faced with her boyfriend's impending trek home, she does her best to cope.


The movie you are looking for is ...
Warm Bodies (2013)

Zombies who were aware of being dead. They were psychologically suffering from observing decaying of their bodies.

R is a young and oddly introspective zombie.

I remember that in the end of the movie this girl jumped out of a balcony and broke her leg, but didn't die and was sad about it





the main character - (the girl I mentioned) was blonde with medium haircut.
Julie is a blonde girl


Thank for your answer, but this movie is not the one I'm looking for - it is too new

Release year: I think between 2010 - 2013 Warm Bodies (2013). Okay then, lol.

I'm sorry, didn't mean to be rude

@nwnebel Nothing to do with being rude, it's that your post's Release year: I think between 2010 - 2013 is false if Warm Bodies is "too new".

yes, it is my post. my statement that warm bodies is too knew is false, I agree.Better  phrase would be 'too expensive', because I belive that movie I'm looking for had low budget and was not very poppular, I will edit my question, thank you

Sounds a lot like Maggie (2015).
"A teenage girl in the Midwest becomes infected by an outbreak of a disease that slowly turns the infected into cannibalistic zombies. During her transformation, her loving father stays by her side."
At key points she despairs over her deteriorating body.
Description of final scene:
She then climbs to the roof and jumps off, her last memories being of herself as a child frolicking outdoors with her mother, picking a daisy.
Some aspects don't seem to match perfectly, but the sense of self decay is, forgive the pun, dead on.

Thank you for you answer, but it is not the movie I'm looking for

Warm Bodies from 2013. Starring Nicholas Hoult and Teresa Palmer?

That's what I thought of.

Welcome to Movies & TV! We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.
